# CMake: Imported libraries as OUTPUT or BYPRODUCTS of another custom command or target

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to extract a static library from a ZIP-file and link against it.

Having the following setting:

```
add_library(COMSDK_LIB STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET COMSDK_LIB PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/tmp/lib/libRTSClientSdk.a")
```

And the imported library being used in another `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib COMSDK_LIB)
```

Would it be possible that the imported library is generated by another `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target`?

I tried the following, but it did **NOT** work:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "/tmp/lib/libRTSClientSdk.a"
    COMMAND unzip -x client_sdk.zip -o /tmp
    DEPENDS client_sdk.zip
)
```

The given error message was:

```
$ ninja
ninja: error: '/tmp/lib/libRTSClientSdk.a', needed by 'mylib.dll', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Your custom command is being executed during `make` step, and it's expecting extracted dependency earlier --- during `cmake` execution. So, basically, You need to get that static library from SDK **before** You're using it in CMake rules or during linkage itself.

Two of possible solutions are listed in [CMake mailing list](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-July/030616.html).

**Solution #1**: (executed in CMake side)

Re-phrasing one of the code snippets, downloading and unzipping is being done during CMake execution:

```
set(CLIENTSDK_ZIP "cliendsdk.zip")
set(CLIENTSDK_URL "http://example.com/${CLIENTSDK_ZIP}")
set(CLIENTSDK_LIB "libRTSClientSdk.a")
set(CLIENTSDK_OUTPUT_DIR "/tmp/sdk/dir")

# Basically just downloading zip file:
message(STATUS "Downloading ${CLIENTSDK_URL}")
execute_process(COMMAND wget ${CLIENTSDK_URL}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CLIENTSDK_OUTPUT_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE errno
  ERROR_VARIABLE err)

if (NOT ${errno} EQUAL 0)
  message(ERROR "Failed downloading ${CLIENTSDK_URL}. Code: ${err}")
endif()

# Extracting downloaded zip file:
message(STATUS "Extracting ${CLIENTSDK_ZIP})
execute_process(COMMAND unzip ${CLIENTSDK_ZIP}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CLIENTSDK_OUTPUT_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE errno
  ERROR_VARIABLE err)

if (NOT ${errno} EQUAL 0)
  message(ERROR "Failed extracting ${CLIENTSDK_ZIP}. Code: ${err}")
endif()

# Importing into CMake scope one library from extracted zip:
add_library(specific_sdk_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(specific_sdk_lib
  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CLIENTSDK_OUTPUT_DIR}/lib/${CLIENTSDK_LIB})

# Adding rule for linking to specific static library from extracted zip:
target_link_libraries(mylib specific_sdk_lib)
```

**Solution #2** (executed in make side):

```
# We must include ExternalProject CMake module first!
include("ExternalProject")

set(CLIENTSDK_URL "http://example.com/clientsdk.zip")
set(CLIENTSDK_LIB "libRTSClientSdk.a")
set(CLIENTSDK_PREFIX "3rd_party")
set(CLIENTSDK_EXTRACTED_DIR
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CLIENTSDK_PREFIX}/src/DownloadClientSDK/")

ExternalProject_Add("DownloadClientSDK"
    PREFIX ${CLIENTSDK_PREFIX}
    URL "${CLIENTSDK_URL}"
    # Suppress ExternalProject configure/build/install targets:
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND "")

add_library(COMSDK_LIB STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(COMSDK_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${CLIENTSDK_EXTRACTED_DIR}/${CLIENTSDK_LIB})

# Require all that download/unzip mumbojumbo only for COMSDK_LIB:
add_dependencies(COMSDK_LIB DownloadClientSDK)

target_link_libraries(my_library COMSDK_LIB)
```

Basically, `CMake` and it's `ExternalProject` module takes care (generates proper `make` targets) of recognizing archive format, unzipping it, and if needed - configuring, building and installing.

Comment: As I used to have the unzip targets as dependencies to other build steps, performing the download and unzip targets during cmake execution is a bit of a compromise to me (because they are always executed). However, it is sufficient in my situation and works for me. Thanks a lot for your contribution!

Comment: @dubbaluga I suppose usually `make` step is executed more often then `cmake` step. It is sufficient to track file changes and it prevents from downloading `clientsdk.zip` in question again and again. Though, I'm not familiar with `ninja` at all (just realized that You're using it instead of `make`) :}

Comment: @dubbaluga, apparently You can get the behavior required using `ExternalProject_Add()`. Just updated my answer :}

Comment: thank you so much for the execute_process(). I was racking my brain with add_custom_target() and add_custom_command()